# No ports found: Error while listing all the ports in python

Tags: python-3.x, port, pyserial, ubuntu-20.04

I tried listing all the com ports so that I can connect to them. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I tried various things that were answered on stackoverflow.
I tried from listing from command line [output of the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNqnb.png)

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
print(ports)
for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        print('hello')
        print("{}: {} [{}]".format(port, desc, hwid))
```

the method serial.tools.list_ports.comports() returns an empty list.
I tried everything and google a lot but I am unable to find a solution.
Pls, help someone because otherwise, my project will come to a halt.

Comment: What do you get if you run `dmesg | grep -i serial` from a terminal?

Comment: [    0.555970] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.562116] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.562120] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.563893] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.563896] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.078359] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.333481] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

Comment: I don't see `tty` anywhere do you actually have a com port on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

For me `serial.tools.port_lists` shows "port not found" but `dmesg` shows the `ttyS3` port does exist:

```
[root@localhost ngt]# dmesg | egrep --color 'serial|ttyS'
[00.751594] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[0.866102] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[0.866117] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[0.866129] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic

[root@localhost ngt]# python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports -v
no ports found
```

So I am able to connect to this `ttyS3` port using `serial.Serial()`.